# Solving Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

Tags: flutter, dart, geocoding

I am working on the turn by turn navigation.

```
Future getReverseGeocodingGivenLatLngUsingMapbox(LatLng latLng) async {
  String query = '${latLng.longitude},${latLng.latitude}';
  String url = '$baseUrl/$query.json?access_token=$accessToken';
  url = Uri.parse(url).toString();
  print(url);
  try {
    _dio.options.contentType = Headers.jsonContentType;
    final responseData = await _dio.get(url);
    return responseData.data;
  } catch (e) {
    final errorMessage = DioExceptions.fromDioError(e as DioError).toString();
    debugPrint(errorMessage);
  }
}
```

The above function is used below

```
    Future<Map> getParsedReverseGeocoding(LatLng latLng) async {
      var response = await getReverseGeocodingGivenLatLngUsingMapbox(latLng);
      Map feature = response['features'][0];
      Map revGeocode = {
        'name': feature['text'],
        'address': feature['place_name'].split('${feature['text']}, ')[1],
        'place': feature['place_name'],
        'location': latLng
      };
      return revGeocode;
    }
```

And the getParsedReverseGeocoding() function is used below

```
void initializeLocationAndSave() async {
    // Ensure all permissions are collected for Locations
    Location _location = Location();
    bool? _serviceEnabled;
    PermissionStatus? _permissionGranted;

    _serviceEnabled = await _location.serviceEnabled();
    if (!_serviceEnabled) {
      _serviceEnabled = await _location.requestService();
    }

    _permissionGranted = await _location.hasPermission();
    if (_permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      _permissionGranted = await _location.requestPermission();
    }

    // Get the current user location
    LocationData _locationData = await _location.getLocation();
    LatLng currentLocation =
    LatLng(_locationData.latitude!, _locationData.longitude!);

    // Get the current user address
    String currentAddress =
       (await getParsedReverseGeocoding(currentLocation))['place'];  // getting error over here

    // Store the user location in sharedPreferences
    sharedPreferences.setDouble('latitude', _locationData.latitude!);
    sharedPreferences.setDouble('longitude', _locationData.longitude!);
    sharedPreferences.setString('current-address', currentAddress);

    Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const Home()), (route) => false);
  }
```

However, I have the following error when the 'place' field is retrieved.

> Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of
> 'index'

Comment: Is your error in this line?     `String currentAddress =
       (await getParsedReverseGeocoding(currentLocation))['place']; `

Comment: yes this is the error line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things that should help you:

- it seems you're missing jsonDecode and:

```dart
Future getReverseGeocodingGivenLatLngUsingMapbox(LatLng latLng) async {
  String query = '${latLng.longitude},${latLng.latitude}';
  String url = '$baseUrl/$query.json?access_token=$accessToken';
  url = Uri.parse(url).toString();
  print(url);
  try {
    _dio.options.contentType = Headers.jsonContentType;
    final responseData = await _dio.get(url);
    final result = jsonDecode(responseData.data);
    return result;
  } catch (e) {
    final errorMessage = DioExceptions.fromDioError(e as DioError).toString();
    debugPrint(errorMessage);
  }
}
```

- it's recommended to use strong typing with Dart, I'm guessing that this should be:

```dart
Future<List<dynamic>> getReverseGeocodingGivenLatLngUsingMapbox(LatLng latLng) async {...
}
```

- And the problem is likely inside the second method:

```dart
Future<Map> getParsedReverseGeocoding(LatLng latLng) async {
    var response = await getReverseGeocodingGivenLatLngUsingMapbox(latLng);

    // This response is likely a List and you don't have key 'features' of type String/index, i.e. you have a index which is supposed to be an int.
    // Map feature = response['features'][0];
    // Maybe this will work: 
    Map feature = response[0];

    Map revGeocode = {
        'name': feature['text'],
        'address': feature['place_name'].split('${feature['text']}, ')[1],
        'place': feature['place_name'],
        'location': latLng
    };
    return revGeocode;
}
```

- cascading calls can make your code harder to read and debug:

```dart
final revGeocode = await getParsedReverseGeocoding(currentLocation);
final currentAddress = revGeocode['place'];

// now you can hover revGeocode and see what's inside using your IDE
```

**In short: use Dart type system to your favor by strongly typing your code as much as possible.**

Comment: Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' on Map feature = response[0]; and final revGeocode = await getParsedReverseGeocoding(currentLocation);

Comment: I am actually using code from https://github.com/Imperial-lord/mapbox-flutter/blob/main/turn_by_turn/completed_code/mapbox_turn_by_turn/lib/helpers/mapbox_handler.dart by following the Youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J1yLPFbjOkE

Comment: What do you get in responseData, does it have any data?

Comment: Upon binding the await getReverseGeocodingGivenLatLngUsingMapbox(latLng); within json.decode() it worked!